# Update an internal library in a Java Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, project, updates

I have developed a little software in java that uses a library (Selenium Standalone Server). I use Eclipse to build an ejecutable jar. The selenium jar is added by the build path.

The problem is that Selenium is getting update frecuently (to be compatible with the principal web browsers).I find myself continually forced to change the library and create a new jar

How this process can be automated ? What would be the best practice to do it?

I understand that the software can check and download the last library of selenium. But how to associate it the generated jar ?

Thanks

Comment: Use Gradle or Maven (both have IDE integration).

Comment: Thanks to open that door @FranzBecker  ... i din't know any of both tools, looks that they provide exactly what i was looking for.